# Vim auto fold when leaving fold

Tags: vim, folding

I would like to have vim auto-close my fold when I leave it. Means when my cursor is in a fold the fold should be shown but when it is (lets say) 5 lines below the foldend it should close again.

These are my folding settings:

```
set foldenable
set foldlevel=0
set foldnestmax=1
set foldmethod=indent
set foldtext=FoldText()

function FoldText()
    return '...'
endfunction
```

Complete source can be found [here](https://github.com/bodokaiser/vimrc)

**How do I do this? As far as I know vim does not offer any options towards this feature so there must be some `autocmd`?**

Bodo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim offers option to do this, it is called `'foldclose'` and to behave like this, set it to `all`.

For more details see the help of it:

```
'foldclose' 'fcl'   string (default "")
            global
            {not in Vi}
            {not available when compiled without the |+folding|
            feature}
    When set to "all", a fold is closed when the cursor isn't in it and
    its level is higher than 'foldlevel'.  Useful if you want folds to
    automatically close when moving out of them.
```

Comment: Any idea how to have the "5 lines below the foldend" behavior ?